# Segmentation Fault when using pointers and classes

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, tree, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to write a code to create a generic tree using stacks, where -1 is for end of node, but I'm unable to figure out where I'm going wrong.
Could anyone debug it for me?
The code is a very simple one though.

I found that the for loop is running only twice, and at the end of second run, there is a seg. fault occurring.

`````
using namespace std;

class Node
{
    public:
    int data;
    vector<Node> *children={nullptr};
};


int main()
{
    int a[]={10,5,4,-1,1,-1,-1,6,-1};
    int n=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    
    stack<Node> s;
    Node root;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==-1)
        s.pop();
        else
        {
            Node temp;
            temp.data=a[i];
            if(s.size()==0)
            {
                root=temp;
            }
            else
            {
                //cout<<temp.data<<endl;
                s.top().children->push_back(temp);
               // cout<<s.top().data<<endl;
            }
            
            s.push(temp);
        }
         //cout<<i<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}````
`````

Comment: Calling `pop` on an empty stack is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Tell us at which line it faults.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I don't think that with the given data popping from an empty stack is ever attempted.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Ah the indentation (or rather lack thereof) threw me of. Still, it might be a good idea to actually *make sure*.

Comment: Given the array inputs, the code doesn't allow pop operation on an empty stack

Answer (score 0):

`children` is a pointer, but you never allocate any memory for it to point to.

There's absolutely no need for pointers here. Change this

```
vector<Node> *children={nullptr};
```

to this

```
vector<Node> children;
```

and this

```
s.top().children->push_back(temp);
```

to this

```
s.top().children.push_back(temp);
```

That should be an improvement, not honestly sure if the code is correct though, even with these changes.

The main benefit of using vectors is to avoid having to handle pointers. So a pointer to a vector very rarely (almost never) make any sense.